# javascript virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I am a java developer, and a biginner in javascript, was looking for a javascript virtual keyboard, found this one :
http://fiddle.jshell.net/FEaSC/show/
copied the source code in my pc , I don't know why the keyboard is invisible when I double clik in the html that has the downloaded code.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to correct the path to the JavaScript file or save it locally.